# What could have caused this API level change?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/23jMD.png
Not allowed to post inline due to low rep.
So today i tried to up a new version of my App to the PlayStore and was greeted with that error .*Shown in image.

Any ideas what could have caused it>?

Answer (score 1):

Your new version supports only api 15-19 while your old version supported 19+. So what its saying is that if a user were to upgrade from API level 15-19 to an API level above 19, they would have to downgrade your app to version 4.0 which is not allowed.

Either make your new APK support 19+ aswell (ie support 15+ would work) or deactivate your old version and then publish the new version, being aware that anybody with API over 19 will not be able to update.

As for what is causing your API version to be 15-19, it is hard to say without seeing your manifest as well as you double checking that you set the APK settings correctly on upload.

Comment: I don't see why it would only support API levels 15-19. There's only a `targetSdkVersion` specified, and I don't see any mention of a `maxSdkVersion` at all. How did Google derive a max API level of 19 for this APK?

Comment: Well how is it being built do you use Android Studio? You might have it in one of your gradle files, or you AndroidManifest. Also on upload I think you can specify as well.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens by the way, how are you connected to this question it looks like it was asked by amas?

Comment: I'm not, I'm just unsure if your answer will suffice to fix the problem. I'm wondering what *caused* the max API level to be set to 19, as the Gradle file seems to be fine. Of course, it might be caused by some other Gradle file / Android manifest - in which case OP will need to provide more details.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens thanks, I didn't notice he had posted the gradle their!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens either way, though the answer to his question is that he can't publish a newer version of the app which has a lower supported max SDK version.